# Lightweight logging library for ASP.NET MVC 2

Tags: logging, asp.net-mvc-2

I need a lightweight logging library for ASP.NET MVC2.
It only needs to support storage of messages in the database and sending emails for critical errors.

What do you recommend besides log4net?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend [ELMAH](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/). It is very easy to deploy, and makes lots of features, among them the ones you mention, available. You basically just drop a dll or two in the bin folder, add a couple of things in web.config and it's done.